I used scanf_s and it is ignored completely
Edit: I honestly don't want to finish the code because a lot of things are very confuse for me. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me fix my terrible code. i have updated the code to the lastest version. I also compiled this with Visual Studio
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std; // wtf

static void copyright()
{
    system("cls");
    string version;
    ifstream file("Version.txt");
    while (getline(file, version)) {
        printf("FormNet %s %c STTV Studios 2024\n", version.c_str(), 184);
    }
    file.close();
}
static void fpause(bool silent = true, string message = "default")
{
    if (silent == true) {
        system("pause >nul");
    }
    else {
        printf(message.c_str() + '\n');
        system("pause >nul");
    }
    return;
}
static int checkeo()
{
    char inp;
    cin >> inp;
    char inp2 = tolower(inp);
    if (inp2 == 's') {
        fpause(false, "Es bueno saberlo");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (inp2 == 'n') {
        copyright();
        fpause(false, "Esta bien, ponga la informacion de nuevo\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 2;
    }
}

static void creacion() {
    printf("Primero, elija un titulo\n");
    string titulo;
    cin >> titulo;
    copyright();
    printf("Ahora escriba su nombre!\n");
    string autor;
    cin >> autor;
    copyright();
    printf("Ahora escriba el precio!\n");
    float precio;
    cin >> precio;
    copyright();
    printf("Procesando...\n");
    printf("Ya tenemos la informacion de su libro\n");
    printf("Esta informacion es correcta? [S, N]\n\n");
    printf("Titulo del libro: %s\n", titulo.c_str());
    printf("Autor del libro: %s\n", autor.c_str());
    printf("Precio del libro: %c%.2f\n", 36, precio);
    int res1 = checkeo();
    if (res1 == 1) {
        return;
    }
    else if (res1 == 0) {
        creacion();
    }
    else {
        copyright();
        fpause(false, "Error inesperado!");
        creacion();
    }
}

int main()
{
    copyright();
    fpause(false, "Hola!");
    fpause(false, "Vamos a crear un libro!");
    creacion();
    fpause(false, "Gracias por llenar el formulario!");
    return 0;
}

I am very new to C++ and it was very easy to use the normal C, I won't probably finish this code until I start to learn C++

Your code after using namespace std looks like a clean C, not C++. Maybe you are studying C?

What is the program input?

@3CxEZiVlQ I was studying C some months ago, so yes. But I just wanted to try C++ and got an error for using scanf() which is something that didn't happen to me with C. I also wanted to use normal C functions instead of weird C++ functions (like cout <<)

"I have a code that checks for user input with scanf_s()." Most likely all your problems are caused by that. Scanf and family are notoriously bad for user input, i.e. for anything that is not reliably following a known syntax.

"// Sorry for putting such a long code" Why not removing extra code as fpause/copyright/system calls.

Where are you learning "C++" from? (your source doesn't seem to do a good job). This almost looks like someone is teaching you "C" as it was used over 30 years ago

@STGamer24 "But I just wanted to try C++ ... I also wanted to use normal C functions instead of weird C++ functions" - then you are not learning C++ properly. You may as well just stick with C and ignore C++ if you are not going to use it the way it is intended to be used. In any case, you are mixing C scanf input with C++ cin input, that is not going to end well.

Side note: I'd strongly recommend using a loop rather than recursion in checkeo() and elsewhere to provide for retries.

Side note: Don't ignore the return code. scanf will tell you how many values were successfully read. If the number isn't what you expect, you owe it to yourself to stop and figure out why. Preferably with tests in the code rather than after the fact in a debugging session. Every error case that you do not trap and handle is going to be time wasted debugging.

@PepijnKramer I searched for C++ functions and used my small C knowledge

@RemyLebeau Thanks for the information. I'll try to add that to my code

"I searched for C++ functions" Using C++ isn't (just) a matter of functions. It is architecture and design. How the pieces fit together and work with each other.

@AviBerger ok, thanks for letting me know. But can you explain a little bit about that?

FYI, in C++ you can pause your input by using std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n);  No need to  involve the operating system.

@ThomasMatthews Ok thanks, now I'm not using system() (I don't know what's wrong with system())

@ThomasMatthews you should use std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() instead of a hard-coded limit.  ignore() has a special case for numeric_limits<streamsize>::max().

@RemyLebeau I'm even more lost now. I'll just try to fix it by myself and actually learn how to use c++

system puts your program on hold, what you want so no harm here, while it starts up and runs another program that waits for someone to press enter. That is overkill compared to the program waiting for the user to hit enter by itself. Worse, you're counting on the system having a pause command. And even worse than that, it's vulnerable to some hole replacing the pause command with, say, a command that erases the hard disk.

That's a bit much for a comment. C has individual data entities and individual action entities to model what you are doing. While C++ has that, it is more focused on entities that combine data and behavior together providing a different type of building block and different ways these building blocks interact. It also has a template facility allowing for creation of families of building blocks that act alike, but work on different entities. Afraid that's probably unclear & incomplete.

If you are interested in using C++, then you can learn more about C++ here learncpp.com.  Information on C++ functionality can be found on cppreference.com. For IO : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/input-with-istream/

@PepijnKramer ok, thank you!

You are mixing C scanf input with C++ cin input, that is not going to end well.  Pick one or the other and stick with it.
You are likely encountering a variation of this issue:
Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?
You have 2 calls to scanf_s() - 1 is reading a float, and then 1 is reading a char. Console input is generally line-buffered, so the user has to type ENTER before your code will see the input.
Both of your scanf_s() calls are not reading the \n (ENTER) from the input. So, for instance, scanf_s("%f", &precio) will read just the number but leave behind the \n for the next scanf_s("%c", &inp, 1) to read, which is not what you want.
When you read formatted input, make sure you read it completely so you don't leave anything behind that should not be left behind.  In this case, add some code to read the trailing \n after (or as part of) each scanf_s() call.

Ok, thanks for letting me know. Thanks to you I could fix the only bug in my code that made it useless
